# How to enumerate files in channel to use `collectFile`

Tags: nextflow

I am trying to enumerate files in a Channel to rename them before using `collectFile`:

```
files.flatten().merge(Channel.fromList([1, 2, 3, 4])).collectFile(storeDir: "$SCRATCH/intermediate") {
    item -> ["data${item[1]}.csv", item[0].text]
}
```

But the [latest](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#merge) documentation says that the `merge` operator for channels is deprecated, but does not point to any alternative that should be used. What can I use instead of `merge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [migration notes](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#dsl2-migration-notes) say to use the [join operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) instead. If your inputs were lists, you could do something like:

```
def indexedChannel( items ) {
    return Channel.from( items.withIndex() ).map { item, idx -> tuple( idx, item ) }
}

ch1 = indexedChannel( [ 15, 20, 21 ] )
ch2 = indexedChannel( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] )
ch3 = indexedChannel( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )

ch1
    .join( ch2 )
    .join( ch3 )
    .view()
```

Results:

```
[0, 15, a, 1]
[1, 20, b, 2]
[2, 21, c, 3]
```

However, the merging/joining of two channels is unnecessary to enumerate. Just use the [map operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map):

```
def c = 1
Channel
    .fromPath( './data/*.txt' )
    .map { tuple( it, c++ ) }
    .collectFile(storeDir: "$SCRATCH/intermediate") { fn, count ->
        ["data${count}.csv", fn.text]
    }
```

Comment: this was my final solution: 
```
files.map {
    items -> items.withIndex()
}.flatten().collate(2).map {
    item, idx -> tuple( idx + 1, item )
}.collectFile(storeDir: "$SCRATCH/intermediate") {
    item -> ["data${item[0]}.csv", item[1].text]
}
```
thank you for your help :)